# ¿Por qué no obtengo el valor de retorno esperado?

Tags: c++

Tengo problemas al momento de regresar el valor de retorno ya que "return Prom;" me devuelve un valor negativo y anormal a los valores que yo ingrese en cin, por ende al momento de evaluar o entrar a la condición si la impresión es errónea. Alguien podría ayudarme a saber que esta mal y enviarme el código corregido. Muchas gracias.

Archivo de encabezado (Calificaciones.h)

```
  class Calificaciones{
public:
    int Promedio();
    void Resultado();

private:
    int Prom;
};
```

Archivo de declaración de funciones (Calificaciones.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Calificaciones.h"

int Calificaciones::Promedio(){
    int Calif1, Calif2, Calif3, Prom;

    cout << "Ingrese la calificacion #1: ";
    cin >> Calif1;
    cout << "Ingrese la calificacion #2: ";
    cin >> Calif2;
    cout << "Ingrese la calificacion #3: ";
    cin >> Calif3;

    Prom = (Calif1 + Calif2 + Calif3) / 3;
    return Prom;
}

void Calificaciones::Resultado(){
    cout << Prom; //Esta linea solo la mande a imprimir para saber el valor que se almaceno en la variable//
    if(Prom > 69){
        cout << "\nEl alumno aprobo su materia \n";
    }else{
        cout << "\nEl alumno reprobo su materia \n";
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Calificaciones.h"

int main(){
    Calificaciones Calif;
    Calif.Promedio();
    Calif.Resultado();
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en la función `Promedio`, retornas un valor que luego no usas en tu función principal y al llamarse la variable local como `Prom` ( mismo nombre que la global de clase) ocupa su sitio y no se actualiza la variable que luego usas en la función `Resultado`.

Sin meterme en la estructuración del código con la que no estoy muy de acuerdo, la función deberia quedarte como esta:

```
int Calificaciones::Promedio()
{
    int Calif1, Calif2, Calif3;   //Hemos quitado la variable local que ocupa el sitio de la variable global.
    cout << "Ingrese la calificacion #1: ";
    cin >> Calif1;
    cout << "Ingrese la calificacion #2: ";
    cin >> Calif2;
    cout << "Ingrese la calificacion #3: ";
    cin >> Calif3;

    Prom = (Calif1 + Calif2 + Calif3) / 3;
    return Prom;  //Return inutil por que luego no se usa
}
```

No lo he probado pero juraría que ese es el problema.

Te pinta valores raros por que realmente te esta pintando la basura de una variable sin inicializar. En otro compilador igual te pintaría 0 o algún valor fijo sin demasiado sentido.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo único que hice fue eliminar la variable Prom segun como tu lo indicaste (//Hemos quitado la variable local que ocupa el sitio de la variable global.), pero siempre debia retornar el Prom; para ser utlizada en la otra funcion de Resultado().

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido

Comment: Pako, tu respuesta es excelente :) mas ampliaría la respuesta con algún consejo para combatir problemas como este en el futuro... ya sea inicializar variables y/o adoptar una notación Húngara para distinguir variables locales de variables miembro. *No puedo resistirme a preguntar... ¿Direla?*

Comment: Evidentment Paw, evidentment.... Por eso dije "Sin meterme en la estructuración del código con la que no estoy muy de acuerdo,"  David ha hecho una estructuración de código y notación que le traerá problemas. No obstante he preferido no decir nada para no liar, dado que son fallos comunes al iniciarse en el mundo de la programación y que creo que se irán resolviendo con el tiempo.